# AllItems.aspx GET parameters

Tags: document-library, parameter

While searching for resources, users on different forums often use GET parameters to customize the display of their document library.
I searched the proper documentation on this page, but could not find any.

Is there proper documentation on all the GET parameters for this page?

As an example I use `https://myorg.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=/my/root/folder`; where can I find all the other parameters like `RootFolder`?

Thank you

Comment: If you're looking for building query string parameters, check out [this old article](https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/03/sharepoint-search-filter-or-sort-lists.html).